# Disable loading all stylesheets in rails6 development

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets, rails-sprockets

I want to load/unload [the specific css debugging bulma structures](https://gist.github.com/JuanVqz/105c4910ff711659059c99492ecd1a5c) by comment/uncomment the line of `stylesheet_link_tag`:

```rb
# app/view/layouts/application.html.erb
...
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

    <%# Bulma %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css', media: 'all' %>
    <%# Debugger on/off by comment/uncomment %>
    <%# <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bulma/debug' %> <- this line!
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
...
```

And my stylesheets dir tree is like this:

```sh
app/assets/stylesheets/
├── application.css
├── bulma
│   ├── debug.css
│   └── grid.css
└── posts.scss
```

But when I comment that line like above, the css file is loaded(and also for grid.css).

I think `link_directory` just the stylesheets dir, cannot load recursively:

```js
# app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

And all the other configs are default to Rails 6.1.3.

Why app/assets/stylesheets/bulma/debug.css is loaded automatically and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your application.css file, you may have a line like `*= require_tree .` This will automatically include everything in your app/assets/stylesheets directory.

Try adding underneath right after that line something like `*= stub 'bulma/debug'`. That should prevent the file from loading.

It's not currently in the rails official rails documentation (from what I can see), but you can find `stub` and related Sprockets methods documented [on Github](https://github.com/rails/sprockets).

Comment: It's about sprockets and I think your suggestion is more railsy way, ACTUALLY sprockets, than a commentation of stylesheet_link_tag line.